# Python+numpy: a lucky floating point case?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I'm inverting a very simple matrix, and I stumbled in something which I don't understand.

EDIT: In the original post I forgot to take care of the fact that numpy defaults to float64, hence the float32 computation was actually happening with double precision. I replaced the original version with a corrected one which casts the matrixes to the correct type before performing the operation.

When using float32 everything seems fine:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: t='float32'

In [3]: np.set_printoptions(precision=50)
```

I need a couple of costants:

```
In [4]: z1 = np.float32((1+np.sqrt(5))/2)

In [5]: z2 = np.float32((1-np.sqrt(5))/2)

In [6]: print "%.50f" % z1
1.61803400516510009765625000000000000000000000000000

In [7]: print "%.50f" % z2
-0.61803400516510009765625000000000000000000000000000

In [8]: print "%.50f" % (z1+z2)
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

C is the main matrix:

```
In [9]: C = np.array([[1., 1.],
   ...:              [z1, z2]]).astype(t)

In [10]: print C
[[ 1.                         1.                       ]
 [ 1.61803400516510009765625 -0.61803400516510009765625]]
```

And Cinv is the inverse:

```
In [11]: Cinv = np.array([[-z2/(z1-z2), 1/(z1-z2)],
   ....:                  [-z1/(z2-z1), 1/(z2-z1)]]).astype(t)

In [12]: print Cinv
[[ 0.2763932049274444580078125  0.447213590145111083984375 ]
 [ 0.723606765270233154296875  -0.447213590145111083984375 ]]
```

Finally, the dot product:

```
In [13]: print np.dot(Cinv, C)
[[  1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+00
    0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+00]
 [ -5.96046447753906250000000000000000000000000000000000e-08
    1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+00]]
```

(EDIT: for the record, performing the same computation with double precision (C and Cinv defaulting to .astype('float64') yields worse results:

```
[[  9.99999999394382443895779033482540398836135864257812e-01
   -6.05617556104220966517459601163864135742187500000000e-10]
 [ -2.91967048315910915334825403988361358642578125000000e-08
    9.99999970803295168408908466517459601163864135742188e-01]]
```

)

That is, multiplying C by it's inverse yelds [[1,0],[0,1]] within float32  precision as expected, which on my machine numpy says to be:

```
In [13]: np.finfo('float32')
Out[13]: finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```

Switching to float64 yields:

```
In [14]: z1 = np.float64((1+np.sqrt(5))/2)

In [15]: z2 = np.float64((1-np.sqrt(5))/2)

In [16]: print "%.50f" % z1
1.61803398874989490252573887119069695472717285156250

In [17]: print "%.50f" % z2
-0.61803398874989490252573887119069695472717285156250

In [18]: print "%.50f" % (z1+z2)
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

In [19]: C = np.array([[1., 1.],
   ....:              [z1, z2]])

In [20]: print C
[[ 1.                                                   1.                                                 ]
 [ 1.6180339887498949025257388711906969547271728515625
  -0.6180339887498949025257388711906969547271728515625]]

In [21]: Cinv = np.array([[-z2/(z1-z2), 1/(z1-z2)],
   ....:                  [-z1/(z2-z1), 1/(z2-z1)]])

In [22]: print Cinv
[[ 0.27639320225002106390377321076812222599983215332031
   0.44721359549995792770360480972158256918191909790039]
 [ 0.72360679774997893609622678923187777400016784667969
  -0.44721359549995792770360480972158256918191909790039]]

In [23]: print np.dot(Cinv, C)
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
```

How comes the result of the last dot product is exact?
I would have expected, as in the float32 case, to get some error, this time in the e-15 region, especially considering that there are divisions and multiplications involved.

```
In [24]: np.finfo('float64')
Out[24]: finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

Moreover, without going again through the intermediate results, float128 yields again a quite good but still perturbated result:

```
In [38]: print np.dot(Cinv, C)
[[ 1.0 -2.710505431213761085018632002174854278564453125e-20]
 [-5.42101086242752217003726400434970855712890625e-20  1.0]]

In [28]: np.finfo('float128')
Out[28]: finfo(resolution=1e-18, min=-1.18973149536e+4932, max=1.18973149536e+4932, dtype=float128)
```

So I guess my question is if there is some particular known optimization going on with float64 on 64 bits processors (i'm getting same results on intel i7 and an old amd64 X2), is it just a lucky case or I am missing something very very important?
I tried this on different python versions (some 2.7.x and 3.x) with the same results.

Post-post small update:

Interestingly enough, in C with doubles I get exact results as well:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double z1 = (1+sqrt(5))/2;
    double z2 = (1-sqrt(5))/2;
    printf("z1 %5.50f\n", z1);
    printf("z2 %5.50f\n", z2);

    double C[2][2];
    C[0][0] = 1;
    C[0][1] = 1;
    C[1][0] = z1;
    C[1][1] = z2;

    double Cinv[2][2];
    Cinv[0][0] = -z2/(z1-z2);
    Cinv[0][1] = 1/(z1-z2);
    Cinv[1][0] = -z1/(z2-z1);
    Cinv[1][1] = 1/(z2-z1);

    double Cres[2][2];

    Cres[0][0] = Cinv[0][0]*C[0][0] + Cinv[0][1]*C[1][0];
    Cres[0][1] = Cinv[0][0]*C[0][1] + Cinv[0][1]*C[1][1];
    Cres[1][0] = Cinv[1][0]*C[0][0] + Cinv[1][1]*C[1][0];
    Cres[1][1] = Cinv[1][0]*C[0][1] + Cinv[1][1]*C[1][1];

    printf("Cres[0][0] %5.50f\n", Cres[0][0]);
    printf("Cres[0][1] %5.50f\n", Cres[0][1]);
    printf("Cres[1][0] %5.50f\n", Cres[1][0]);
    printf("Cres[1][1] %5.50f\n", Cres[1][1]);


    return 0;
}
```

yields:

```
z1 1.61803398874989490252573887119069695472717285156250
z2 -0.61803398874989490252573887119069695472717285156250
Cres[0][0] 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cres[0][1] 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cres[1][0] 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cres[1][1] 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is in total accordance with the python code. I think it can be safely concluded that this particular computation is just a lucky coincidence and we get exact results. In fact, using a different root for the zs (say sqrt(2)), yields perturbated results.

For the record, the same computation with all floats yields:

```
z1 1.61803400516510009765625000000000000000000000000000
z2 -0.61803400516510009765625000000000000000000000000000
Cres[0][0] 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cres[0][1] 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Cres[1][0] -0.00000005960464477539062500000000000000000000000000
Cres[1][1] 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

again in total accordance with the corrected version of the python code float32 version.

Comment: You're not missing anything important.  Some run-time environments round off results that are within a certain tolerance of a convenient value.  It's also possible that you got lucky with such a simple example.  Since the chips generally round their results, it's hardly unthinkable that some roundings will counterbalance.

  Have you tried this with any other combinations -- especially a larger matrix?  A 4x4 should be enough to clear up doubts.

Comment: Standard Python floating point numbers have a `.hex()` method that can give you the bit pattern unambiguously. If `numpy` does as well, you can figure out if those results were exact or simply rounded for display.